# Best practices for user management with Play! Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, crud

What's the recommended way to handle user management in Play! Framework?

This is my setup:

- `UserAwareControllerBase` as a base class for controllers
- The main view template includes a login/logout button
- custom `Security` class extending `Secure.Security`, and controllers that only allow signed-in users are annotated with `@With(Secure.class)`

(I haven't implemented a real password/login system yet, just entering the correct email suffices to login. TBD)

The setup is nice because Controllers don't need to bother writing user management code, and can easily get the signed-in user by calling `getUser()`. However, I'm already starting to feel the limitations of this setup. I'm getting a convoluted inheritance hierarchy, and am facing a problem if I want to inherit from the [CRUD class](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/current/crud).

What's the best practice for handling user authentication/authorization in Play! without repeating code?

**UserAwareControllerBase.java**

```
public abstract class UserAwareControllerBase extends Controller {
    protected final static UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();

    @Before
    static void setConnectedUser() {
        if(Security.isConnected()) {
            User user = userRepo.findByEmail(Security.connected());
            renderArgs.put("user", user);
        }
    }

    static User getUser() {
        return renderArgs.get("user", User.class);
    }
}
```

**template.html**

```
<div id='header'>
  ...

  #{if user}
   <a href="@{Secure.logout()}">Log out (${user.email})</a>
  #{/if}
  #{else}
    <a href="@{Secure.login()}">Log in</a>
  #{/else}
</div>
```

**Security.java**

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {
    protected final static UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();

    static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        User user = userRepo.findByEmail(username);
        return user != null;
    }

    public static void onDisconnected() {
        Application.index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share code between controllers, prefer using the @With annotation rather than using inheritance.

For user management, I am used to put some rights in the session in the onAuthenticated method like this

```
static void onAuthenticated() {
    session.put(Const.MY_RIGHT, true);
}
```

And then my check method is

```
static boolean check(String profile) {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(session.get(profile));
}
```

With this I can use the @check annotation to check user rights. In the onAuthenticated method you can do whatever you want to map complex rights managements into simple constants.

Comment: Google doesn't seem to know where the documentation for @With is.